# Rails create method: hidden field tag submitting but not working & sessions param not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, parameters

I have a the following form I'm trying to submit (from the show method view):

```
  <%= form_for(Photo.new, :remote => true, html: {multipart: :true}) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :title, 'Title' %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>

    <%= f.label :image, 'Choose Image' %>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :item_id, :value => @item.id %>
    <%= f.submit 'Add' %>

  <% end %>
```

And I'm trying to use the following create method:

```
def show
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
end

def create
    @item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
    @photo = Photo.new(photo_params)
    redirect_to edit_photos_url, notice: 'Photo uploaded' if @photo.save
end
```

This is what the logs generate:

```
Started POST "/photos" for ::1 at 2015-07-03 21:17:10 -0400
Processing by PhotosController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "photo"=>{"title"=>"sdb", "image"=>#    <ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe301a2ebf8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/d8/hx2wgfwx7m77c6mjwx2pffcc0000gq/T/RackMultipart20150703-35083-rt86ai.png>, @original_filename="Screen Shot 2015-06-28 at 9.23.31 PM.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo[image]\"; filename=\"Screen Shot 2015-06-28 at 9.23.31 PM.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, "item_id"=>"27"}, "commit"=>"Add"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Item without an ID):
  app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:13:in `create'
```

The `item_id` seems to be submitted, yet it doesn't work ?

I've tried also implementing sessions, which would be more ideal. I've done the following in the `create` method of the items controller:

```
remember_item @item
```

Calling the method in the helper:

```
def remember_item(item)
  cookies.permanent.signed[:item_id] = item.id
  session[:item_id] = item.id
end
```

I've checked the session variables, and the `:item_id` did get passed correctly in the session. I've tried the following:

```
def create
    @item = Item.find(session[:item_id])
    @photo = @item.photos.build(photo_params)
    redirect_to edit_photos_url, notice: 'Photo uploaded' if @photo.save
end
```

And this also doesn't work, giving the following error:

```
Couldn't find Item without an ID
```

I'd really like to get the latter to work. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The item_id is included in the photo params

```
@item = Item.find params[:photo][:item_id]
```

Should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely, what you are submitting is actually

```
params
=> {photo: {item_id: 1, **other_attrs}}
params[:item_id]
=> nil
params[:photo][:item_id]
=> 1
```

That is because `item_id` is in your form as a helper and the form helper thinks it is a property of `photo`.